# Google+ posting issue. Snippet not appearing correctly

Tags: google-plus

For some reason, when we try to post a link to our blog it doesn't show the actual blog post title or the snippet. It used to do it in the past and I've attached an additional screen shot. Our website zamansky.com and it doesn't seem to contain any code that I'm aware of that's causing this. Any help why this is happening and how to fix it would be greatly appreciated!

Here's a link to the screen shot: 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the [structured data testing tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/) provided by Google you can see the data found is:

```
WebSite
url:    http://www.zamansky.com/
name:   Zamansky LLC
alternateName:  Zamansky LLC
```

That matches  what is shown for the snippet. Looking back at your sites source code and you'll find:

```
<script type='application/ld+json'>
    {
        "@context":"http:\/\/schema.org",
        "@type":"WebSite",
        "url":"http:\/\/www.zamansky.com\/",
        "name":"Zamansky LLC",
        "alternateName":"Zamansky LLC"
    }
</script>
```

This is the microdata the data tool is finding. Since Google+ Snippets [prioritize schema.org data first](https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/#documentation) that's what's getting used. You can simply make sure the `ld+json` attributes are set to match what's in the `og` tags and you should be all set.

Keep in mind that the details shown in Google+ share previews might be cached and may not show the latest updates immediately.